# iOS swift strange behaviour tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

my app is in portrait mode only, but a few viewcontroller (to read a pdf) have the option to be in landscape mode.
 I am using this function to allow the landscape mode

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
if let rootViewController = self.topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: window?.rootViewController) {
    if (rootViewController.responds(to: Selector(("canRotate")))) {
// Unlock landscape view orientations for this view controller
return .allButUpsideDown;
}
}
// Only allow portrait (standard behaviour)
return .portrait;
}
```

then in landscape mode if we press the back button, I force the previous viewcontroller to go back to portrait mode using this function

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated : Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController) {
        UIDevice.current.setValue(Int(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue), forKey: "orientation")
    }
}
```

it is working perfectly on the iPhones (plus) the previous page comes back to portrait mode and the tab bar is fine but there is a bug that appears only on iPhone no plus (with a smaller resolution) the previous page comes back in portrait mode but there is a glitch with the tab bar.

[image: picture]

does anyone have an idea? I have no idea what's going on..

Comment: Can you share the code where you draw the images for each `UITab`?

Comment: I don't have any code, I used the storyboard to create the UITab

Answer (score 0):

I "fixed" the issue by removing

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated : Bool) {
super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController) {
    UIDevice.current.setValue(Int(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue), forKey: "orientation")
}
```

in the child view

and by adding this in the parent view.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    UIDevice.current.setValue(Int(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue), forKey: "orientation")
}
```

I still don't understand the bug but at least there is a workaround...

note that if I put this code in viewWillAppear, I am getting the same bug